# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

This is the responce i am getting when trying to upload a file from my client(PHP),My server is on WebApi which is hosted in one server.In my webapi i have allowed all CORS related things still i am getting this error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) tutorial?

Maybe when you say

> In my webapi i have allowed all CORS related things

you didn't do that correctly, or maybe you enabled too many options at the same time.
It's hard to give you more details without access to your actual configuration.

There are also many posts on the same subject here on SO, have you checked them?

Comment: Hi Luca, As per your suggestation i have implemented all the setting the site have.but still my PHP client are unable to post file in my server.